# Is there a way to display a html document hosted in a SharePoint 2016 document library using iframe?

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-on-prem, iframe

Im trying to embed a html file, which is hosted in a SharePoint 2016 library, inside of an iframe on a none SharePoint-Site. Currently im getting "sites.sharepoint.com refused to connect".
If i try to embed a SharePoint-Site it works just fine.

Things i've tried so far:

Adding sandbox="allow-same-origin" to the iframe.

Central Administration -> Manage web applications -> General Settings -> Browser File Handling changed to "Permissive"

Answer (score 0):

There is a **SPFx** webpart (works on modern pages) available on GitHub by Microsoft called react-script-editor. You can install this webpart to your site collection and then use below code to insert the html into an iframe.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#iframeContainer").attr("src","https://siteurl/page.html");
     });
</script>

<iframe  id="iframeContainer" src=""></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i try to embed the html file in a non sharepoint site.